# I am trying to generate a list of all the subsets r, of the set, n. My code works if n-r=2, but if > 2, prints out incorrect output

Tags: c++, set, factorial, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to generate a list of subsets from a set. For example, if I had n = 6, and r = 4, I would have 15 possible combinations which would be the following:

```
0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 4
0 1 2 5
0 1 3 4
0 1 3 5 
0 1 4 5 
0 2 3 4
0 2 3 5
0 2 4 5
0 3 4 5
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 5
1 2 4 5 
1 3 4 5
2 3 4 5
```

My current code does work with the above subsets if n = 6 & r = 4. It also works if any other combination of n-r=2. It does not work for anything else and I'm having a bit of trouble debugging since my code makes perfect sense to me. The code I have is the following:

```
int array[r];
int difference = n-r;

for(int i = 0; i < r; i++){
    array[i] = i;
}

while (array[0] < difference){
        print (array, r);
        for(int i = r-1; i >= 0; i--){
            if ((array[i] - i) == 0){
                array[i] = array[i] + 1;
                for (int j = i+1; j < r; j++){
                    array[j] = j + 1;
                }
                i = r;
            }
            else{
                array[i] = array[i] + 1;
            }
            print (array, r);
        }
    }
}
```

To give some context, when I plug in n=6 and r=3, I am supposed to have 20 combinations as the output. Only 14 are printed, however:

```
0 1 2
0 1 3
0 1 4
0 2 3
0 2 4
0 3 4
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
2 3 4
2 3 4
2 3 5
2 4 5 
3 4 5
```

It does print the first and last output correctly, however I need to have all the outputs printed out and correct. I can see after the 3rd iteration, the code starts failing as it goes from 0 1 4 to 0 2 3 when it should go to 0 1 5 instead. Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Probably a bug. Providing a [mcve] that includes what you mean by "does not work" may speed up your getting an answer.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code, Especially when going from 3rd to 4th iteration to see what works different from your expectation?

Comment: I have, yes. I understand that there's a pattern with the value stored in array with the slot number. So for the above example, if you subtract the array's value with the slot number, the pattern would look like: (0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2) I've noticed with every 2, that's when the code fails. I did originally write the code when the pattern was (0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1...etc.), which is why if n-r=2 works. However, I feel that since I have the else statement, it would take care of everything else including the 2 in the pattern, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think you are trying to do.  As far as I can tell, your main problem is that the main `for` loop should start over after incrementing an array element to a valid value, rather than continuing.

So this version only calls `print` in one place and uses `break` to get out of the main `for` loop.  It also counts the combinations found.

```
#include <iostream>

void print(int array[], int r) {
    for(int i=0; i<r; ++i) {
        std::cout << array[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    static const int n = 6;
    static const int r = 3;

    static const int difference = n-r;
    int array[r];
    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }
    int count = 0;
    while(array[0] <= difference) {
        ++count;
        print(array, r);
        for(int i=r-1; i>=0; --i) {
            ++array[i];
            if(array[i] <= difference + i) {
                for(int j=i+1; j<r; ++j) {
                    array[j] = array[j-1] + 1;
                }
                break;
    }   }   }
    std::cout << "count: " << count << '\n';
}
```

Outputs

```
0 1 2 
0 1 3 
0 1 4 
0 1 5 
0 2 3 
0 2 4 
0 2 5 
0 3 4 
0 3 5 
0 4 5 
1 2 3 
1 2 4 
1 2 5 
1 3 4 
1 3 5 
1 4 5 
2 3 4 
2 3 5 
2 4 5 
3 4 5 
count: 20
```